# Cookies with "[]" symbols aren't parsed by Java servlets

Tags: java, servlets, cookies

I've tried sending cookies like "test[]=111" to Java servlets, and the systems (Tomcat, Jetty) ignore the cookie and do not populate it.

The same cookie is valid on a PHP system and also on the browser. Is "test[]" a valid cookie name? Or if so, since most browsers seem to support it, why is it ignored on Java servlets?

Answer (score 2):

According to [RFC-6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4), a cookie name is a `token`.

[RFC-2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-2.2) defines a `token` as:

```
   token          = 1*<any CHAR except CTLs or separators>
   separators     = "(" | ")" | "<" | ">" | "@"
                  | "," | ";" | ":" | "\" | <">
                  | "/" | "[" | "]" | "?" | "="
                  | "{" | "}" | SP | HT
```

Your cookie name is invalid as `[]` fall into the "separators" category.